# Convert string in the form of a dictionary to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a user input:

```
{“Alert”:3, “Beep”: 41 , “Cry”: 8}
```

How can I convert this to a dictionary so that I can process like one..?

I am able to do it by removing those braces and then separating each key value by splitting and so on. Is there any other simple method to do so?

Comment: Try `ast.literal_eval()`

Comment: @pylang literal_eval*

Comment: Just realized this is a big dupe :)

Comment: @RafaelC : thanks Bro. I got the answer down here.

Answer (score 2):

```
import ast


s = '{"Alert":3, "Beep": 41 , "Cry": 8}'

ast.literal_eval(s)
# {'Alert': 3, 'Beep': 41, 'Cry': 8}
```

Comment: thank you, got my code cleaner

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways of doing it

#### `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
inp='''{"Alert":3, "Beep": 41 , "Cry": 8}'''

ast.literal_eval(inp)
```

#### `json.loads`

If it always follows `json` pattern,

```
import json
json.loads(inp)
{'Alert': 3, 'Beep': 41, 'Cry': 8}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. got my code cleaner